# Which tense to use in a sentence describing past, present and future at the same time

Tags: grammar

Today is Monday.  I'm off from Wednesday last week to Wednesday this week.
Which tense should I use describing this situation?

> 1) I've been off since last Wednesday till this Wednesday. 
>  2) I was off from last Wednesday till this Wednesday. 
>  3) I'm off from last Wednesday till this Wednesday.

Which one is most appropriate to say?   Could you help me?

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, but each answer is slightly different.  I'm not sure which one to choose as the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3) may be OK, but still it seems strange.
I would say:

> I've been off since last Wednesday, and will be off till this Wednesday.

I would use two phrases, otherwise the tenses are kind of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

*I was...* is not possible because it's still Monday and you are 'off' till coming Wednesday. *I have been...* is also not okay. Had it been Wednesday **today**, it would have made some sense. Something like *I have been 'off' since last Wednesday.* *Have been...* denotes something *from the past* till *date.*

Yes, the third one sounds okay (tense wise). I'm off from last Wednesday till this Wednesday. Though the sentence could be better in structure.

If it's Monday, I'd prefer...

> I am *off duty* from the last Wednesday till this Wednesday

Comment: That sounds weird for the same reason as sentence 1, in my opinion.

Comment: @rjh Aw... I never wanted to use *have been*... thanks for drawing my attention. *Have been* in this context is absolutely not natural.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when you refer to the break:

During the break: I've been off since Wednesday, (and don't go back to work) until next Wednesday. -or- I've been off since Wednesday for a week.

After the break: I took a week off starting last Wednesday.

Answer (score 0):

> 3) I'm off from last Wednesday till this Wednesday.

It's monday, you're still off. Your break is in the present.

> 1) I've been off since last Wednesday

works only if you leave it there.

2 is wrong, it would only be right on Thursday or later in that week.

It sounds better if you specify "off work" or "off school" or "off duty" unless it's in direct response to someone asking about you being off work/etc.

Comment: Thank you for the last part of advice.  I didn't realize it. It is helpful.